# Resolving a variable in $(document).on("click", <id-variable>,function)

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a HTML code that extracts variables from JSON as :

```
         <textarea id="{{textarea_id}}" class="comment-insert-text" style = "border: 1px solid #e1e1e1"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div id="{{btn_id}}" style = "margin: 2px 2px 0 0;width:26px;height: 25px;"class="comment-post-btn-wrapper">
                        C
                        </div>
```

The variables for id are also stored in a hidden temporary variable as:

I want to resolve these variables into a javascript file which executes an onclick function. The function takes in the id variable which is not always static. This dynamic variables are the one, passed to the temporary variable through JSON :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("click",<id-name to be resolved here> , function() {
        alert("yes");
        comment_post_btn_click();
    });



    $(document).on("click", "#comm_first_1", function() {
        $('.comment-insert-text').css('border', '1px solid #e1e1e1 ');
    });

});





function comment_post_btn_click()
{

    var _tt = $('#textarea_id').val();
    alert("in");
    //Text within the textarea which the person has entered
        var _comment = $('<id-name variable>').val();

    var _Userid = 1;
    //   Hard coded the name, should be a session name like $('#Userid').val()
    var _Username = "Username_sagar";
    //   Hard coded the name, should be a session name like $('#Username').val()
    if (_comment.length > 0)
    {
        // proceed with ajax callback
        $("#comm_first_1").css('border', '1px solid #e1e1e1');

        $.post("comment_insert.php",
                {
                    task: "comment_insert",
                    Userid: _Userid,
                    comment: _comment
                }
        )
                .error(
                        function()
                        {
                            console.log("Error: ");
                        }

                )
                .success(
                        function(data)
                        {
                            //sucess
                            //insert html into the ul/li
                            comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data)); // converts the text which we receive into a javascript object
                            console.log("ResponseText: " + data);


                        }
                );
        console.log(_comment + "Username: " + _Username + "Userid: " + _Userid);
    }
    else
    {
        // the textarea is empty, put a border on it
        $('.comment-insert-text').css('border', '1px solid #ff0000');
        console.log("The textarea is empty");

    }

    //remove the textarea and ready for another comment
    $('#comm_first_1').val("");

}

function comment_insert(data) {

    var t = '';
    t += '<li class="comment-holder" id="_' + data.comment_id + '">';
    t += '<div class="user-img">';
    t += '<img src="' + data.profile_img + '" class="user-img-pic" />';
    t += '</div>';
    t += '<div class="comment-body">';
    t += '<h3 class="username-field" >' + data.Username + '</h3>';
    t += '<div class="comment-text">' + data.comment + '</div>';
    t += '</div>';
    t += '<div class="comment-buttons-holder">';
    t += '<ul>';
    t += '<li class="delete-btn">[x]</li>';
    t += '</ul>';
    t += '</div>';
    t += '</li>';

    $('.comments-holder-ul').prepend(t);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to add a class to the textarea?  I would just use a class selector instead of trying to find the ids.

Comment: no you don't, I'll show you what I mean...hold on.

Comment: Sure, I need to resolve the ID name in var _comment = $('<id-name variable>').val();

Comment: No, you don't.  Once the click event happens you already have the jquery object as the `this` object.  Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the click event to the class, not the id, then pass the `this` object to the function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".comment-insert-text").click(function() {
            alert("yes");
            comment_post_btn_click(this);
        });



        $(document).on("click", "#comm_first_1", function() {
            $('.comment-insert-text').css('border', '1px solid #e1e1e1 ');
        });

    });





    function comment_post_btn_click(textArea)
    {

        var _tt = $('#textarea_id').val();
        alert("in");
        //Text within the textarea which the person has entered
            var _comment = $(textArea).val();

        var _Userid = 1;
        //   Hard coded the name, should be a session name like $('#Userid').val()
        var _Username = "Username_sagar";
        //   Hard coded the name, should be a session name like $('#Username').val()
        if (_comment.length > 0)
        {
            // proceed with ajax callback
            $("#comm_first_1").css('border', '1px solid #e1e1e1');

            $.post("comment_insert.php",
                    {
                        task: "comment_insert",
                        Userid: _Userid,
                        comment: _comment
                    }
            )
                    .error(
                            function()
                            {
                                console.log("Error: ");
                            }

                    )
                    .success(
                            function(data)
                            {
                                //sucess
                                //insert html into the ul/li
                                comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data)); // converts the text which we receive into a javascript object
                                console.log("ResponseText: " + data);


                            }
                    );
            console.log(_comment + "Username: " + _Username + "Userid: " + _Userid);
        }
        else
        {
            // the textarea is empty, put a border on it
            $('.comment-insert-text').css('border', '1px solid #ff0000');
            console.log("The textarea is empty");

        }

        //remove the textarea and ready for another comment
        $('#comm_first_1').val("");

    }

    function comment_insert(data) {

        var t = '';
        t += '<li class="comment-holder" id="_' + data.comment_id + '">';
        t += '<div class="user-img">';
        t += '<img src="' + data.profile_img + '" class="user-img-pic" />';
        t += '</div>';
        t += '<div class="comment-body">';
        t += '<h3 class="username-field" >' + data.Username + '</h3>';
        t += '<div class="comment-text">' + data.comment + '</div>';
        t += '</div>';
        t += '<div class="comment-buttons-holder">';
        t += '<ul>';
        t += '<li class="delete-btn">[x]</li>';
        t += '</ul>';
        t += '</div>';
        t += '</li>';

        $('.comments-holder-ul').prepend(t);
    }
```

Comment: I tried using:


        $(".comment-insert-text").click(function() {
            alert("yes");
            comment_post_btn_click(this);
        });


And also:

 
    $(document).on("click",'.comment-insert-text', function() {
        alert("yes");
        comment_post_btn_click(this);
    });

However, there is no success, could you help further?

Comment: Sure, but you need to give me more.  What does "no success" mean?  Did the clickevent not fire?  Did it fire, but you couldn't get the value?

Comment: It invokes the function: 
function comment_post_btn_click() when the button is clicked based of the id, your solution calls the same function when the textarea itself is clicked on

Comment: gotcha, my mistake. hold on.

Comment: Can you update your question, instead of saying 'id' specify which id goes where so I can better understand.